# Why didn't Tri-Klops see He-Man hiding in Castle Grayskull?

Tags: plot-explanation, he-man

In the first episode of He-Man (1983), Skeletor approaches Castle Grayskull with his cronies, and says:

> Without He-Man to defend it, Castle Grayskull will be ours!

Then the door is forced open, with the help of Tri-Klops, revealing He-Man behind the door. Tri-Klops has the ability to see through objects. Why didn't he see He-Man?

Comment: I think he is triclops, cyclops is from x-men. May be the door was enchanted?

Comment: @rps *"May be the door was enchanted?"* - So you mean *"a wizard did it"*? ;-)

Comment: @rps He is [Tri-Klops](http://he-man.wikia.com/wiki/Tri-Klops). Edited it in question.

Comment: @rps: Thanks, I just mis-heard/remembered the name...

Comment: @ChristianRau, :) No, I had a [sorceress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorceress_of_Castle_Grayskull) in mind when I said that

Comment: As the quoted dialogue suggests, Skeletor didn't expect He-Man to be there, so there was no reason for Tri-Klops to 'Gamma-scan' the castle. Was it smart not to double check? Well, Skeletor underestimating He-Man is basically a trope.

Answer (score 2):

May be the Castle Grayskull's doors are X-ray proof.

On a serious note think about this Castle grayskull holds the secret of Eternia and all the elder's powers if Tri-Klops could peek into its doors it wouldn't make it much of a fortress really.

Also I think that Sorceress magic is powerful even though it's not powerful compared to Skeletor's but I assume its good enough to give a primary layer to the Castle Grayskull which I presume would've stopped Tri-Klops' vision.

PS: I have vague memories of the 83 show I am basing this answer on the new Heman show which came out in 2000.